# Howto compress time-series data in Matlab (e.g. delta-rle)?

Tags: matlab, time-series, compression

We have terabytes of time-series data, handled with Matlab, filling our disks.

I know that rle-compression could greatly reduce the storage requirement of time-series data, if it were delta-encoded (or even delta-of-delta).

(Reason: The differences between consecutive values are mostly small, often just 0, +1, -1, and rle-compression works great if data contains some values much more often than others.)

As the admin I want our Matlab-users to save disk space. Is there an easy way to do this in Matlab? Ideally mostly transparent, so they do not need to manually rewrite all places in their scripts where they access data.

I don't even need the actual compression, because the filesystem already does that, just automatic delta-encoding would be sufficient.

Comment: Are the data files in Matlab's native format (`.mat`)? If so you can't save much space, because that format already [includes compression by default](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html). If not, how are you (or your users) reading the files from Matlab? Maybe run-length decoding could be easily incorporated into the reading process

Comment: Compressing time-series data only works well if it is delta-encoded. I doubt that the default save function does that, because it does not know that the data is time-series data.

Comment: I have done some quick tests and it does seem to compress in that case, compared with random independent data. But I don't know your values (are they integer? Are they interger-typed?). Also, you haven't addressed my question. You need to provide details about used format and typical data values, otherwise it is hard to help